# How do I handle a key press in MFC?

Tags: events, mfc, keyboard

I want to intercept the keys that are pressed when one of my dialogs is displayed

Comment: Language, platform etc. MVC is generic and used on Web, Windows, Mobile devices. I can easily give you and answer for ASP.NET MVC but have no idea if that is what you want.

Comment: @Craig: MFC=Microsoft Foundation Classes. C++

Comment: Sorry, been working too much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either set up some accelerators that send the relevant WM_COMMAND or respond to WM_KEYDOWN/UP messages and look out for your key presses.

More info here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/pretransdialog01.aspx

And the useful code from that article:

```
BOOL CPreTransTestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
    if(pMsg->message==WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if(pMsg->wParam==VK_RETURN)
            pMsg->wParam=VK_TAB;
    }   
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: To adapt it to work with other keys look at [WINUSER.H](http://www.woodmann.com/fravia/sources/WINUSER.H)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [hooking keyboard events.](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/keyboard/article.php/c5699) That's a CodeGuru link but there are many, many resources available when you google for [How to hook keyboard events with MFC.](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=codeproject+mfc+hook+events#hl=en&expIds=17259,17315,23628,23670,23945,25041,25646,25907,26761,26849,26869,27520,27613,27642,27744,27796,27862,27868,27889,27936&sugexp=leprodsca4&xhr=t&q=how+to+hook+keyboard+events+with+mfc&cp=28&qe=aG93IHRvIGhvb2sga2V5Ym9hcmQgZXZlbnRzIHdpdGggbWZj&qesig=iseoVOzl_yZLHJEADVzFWw&pkc=AFgZ2tlgbfmVWZKfa85Ks3jvO-h0hCvv1fi8rbDPBn901bMEhOcBQuD5N3_KzZGcaDhZrhyB4JtVOTJaE2FiMOkj2dSK8gA3wQ&pf=p&sclient=psy&rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=how+to+hook+keyboard+events+with+mfc&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=4488cb887e893d25)

What you'll find in those articles is that keyboard and/or event hooking is the terminology of choice. "Intercept" is rately used to describe the process. And one more note: Be careful where you hook! You can hook into your dialog or at several other levels. (Btw, key loggers are well-known trojans that employ this tactic. Just an FYI.)

Comment: Thanks. I probably wasn't clear, but I am trying to intercept keys for a dialog that I am creating, not another program's dialog. I want to be able to easily activate debugging functions

Comment: Keyboard hooking will work whether the target window is your creation or not. The process is usually used to hook other windows but can be used to hook your own.