# capturing keys pressed on the keyboard in mfc application

Tags: mfc, keypress

I am new to mfc. I have created an mfc application, I am trying to capture if character keys were pressed.
I have added ON_WM_CHAR to the message map and have written an onChar function to perform some function when a particular character is pressed.

But even if any character is pressed, I do not reach my onChar function.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352462/how-do-i-handle-a-key-press-in-mfc

Answer (score 0):

What class's OnChar have you overloaded? Most such input should typically be handled in a view class.